# how to freeze a row and a columns in an excel file using xlsxwriter in python

Tags: python, excel, freeze, xlsxwriter

I want to freeze the first row and the first column in my excel file using  xlsxwriter in python, I tried the bellow code, and seems like that it freeze just the column, when I remove the second line on the code that freeze the column, it freezes the first row, seems like the second line in the code overwrite the first one.

```
worksheet.freeze_panes(1, 0) # # Freeze the first row.
worksheet.freeze_panes(0, 1) # Freeze the first column.
```

I checked the documentation [here](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/example_panes.html) , seems like no help there.
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this linne and it did the work for me!!

```
worksheet.freeze_panes(1, 1) # # Freeze the first row and column
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing.

Comment: I have to freeze a single middle row, can I achieve this?